# Find all lat/long pairs within a given distance from a lat/long pair

Tags: database, algorithm, distance, haversine

I have a database with millions of lat/long pairs. I would like to implement a function to gather all lat/long pairs within a specified distance from a given lat/long pair. Is there a better way to do this than by iterating over each pair in the database and computing the distance between that pair and the given pair? I'd like to avoid brute force if I can avoid doing so!

I would like to add that I will never be searching for lat/long pairs greater than 1 mile from the given lat/long pair.

Answer (score 2):

Many databases support storage of spatial types directly, and include spatial queries.  This will handle the distance computation *correctly* for you, as well as provide a far more efficient means of pulling the information.

For examples, see:

- [Spatial Data in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx)
- [Geometric types in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/datatype-geometric.html)
- [MySQL Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)
- [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index)

Comment: Let's say I have a database full of house locations and I routinely need to find all houses within 1 mile of a given lat/long. I guess it would be prudent to represent the lat/long of each house with a `Point` type in my SQL Server database, right?

Comment: @RouteMapper Yes, and also make sure it's indexed: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a way to implement the algorithm that selects only those records with `Points` within, say, 1 mile of a given `Point`.

Comment: @RouteMapper See the example queries here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx  The key is to use STDistance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933952.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Reed. Got any examples using C#? I would much rather abstract this sort of thing using LINQ :)

Comment: @RouteMapper It's supported in EF 5+, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859721.aspx

Comment: Perfect. Time to install VS 2012 then. 2010 just won't cut it!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is cluster the database beforehand. In this case you would divide the database into, say, 3-mile clusters. Then when you do the search you only need to compare points within the same cluster.

Comment: What if the lat/long we are comparing each other lat/long against is random?

Comment: You said you have the locations "in a database". If they are in a database they can be clustered.

Comment: The "given" lat/long is something a user can specify and does not necessarily reside in the database.

Comment: When the user gives the input, first you find out what clusters it is in (each cluster will have a specific center and radius), then compare the input to the other points in the clusters.

Comment: That sounds like it could work. Is there a way to do that within SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Yes, but I would rather have my nuts chewed off by a rotweiler than write SQL Server code, so you will have to find someone else to do it.